pushd within a pipeline says it's adding to the stack, but it's not?
I'm working on a modification of this approach to automatically saving and restoring bash's directory stack state when using pushd and popd.
For some reason, my code to restore the saved state isn't working -- I'm calling pushd on the right entries, and it says it's pushing those onto the stack, but afterwards, dirs -v is unchanged!
I have some directories, one per line, in a file, and I'm using this to recreate the stack:
tac $BASH_DIR_STACK_FILE | sort | uniq | while read -r dir
do
    echo $dir
    pushd -n "$dir" > /dev/null
done

When I run that, it works as expected, and claims to be pushing each of the directories. But afterwards, when I do dirs -v, there's no change to the stack!
Using pushd manually for the same directories works as expected.
I also tried the declare approach with $DIRSTACK from this post but that doesn't work either.
Why isn't my directory stack getting updated via pushd inside that loop?

Because the RHS of the pipe is executed in a separate subshell? try while ... done < <(tac "$BASH_DIR_STACK_FILE" | sort | uniq)

That works. But it's very counterintuitive; I can do cat foo | sort and sort < foo and the result is the same, which is why I expected the same kind of behavior from while. But thinking about it more, I can see the difference: for the sort example, I only care about what ends up in stdout and don't care about the internal state of sort while it works. But for the while loop, I am relying on it changing the state of my (current) shell.

Not all shells run the last part of a pipeline in a subshell, see the other linked post. Bash has the lastpipe option to control that
